# How do I get the old value of a select in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-handler

I have an ui:inputSelect in a nested component, I want to know how to get the old value when you select another option.

```
<ui:inputSelect aura:id="cboProducto" class="slds-select" change="{!c.selectProd}">
    <ui:inputSelectOption label="Seleccionar Producto"  text="" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.prodDisponibles}" var="prod">
         <ui:inputSelectOption label="{!prod.Nombre}"  text="{!prod.Id}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

I tried different approches:

#### Getting the old value from the change method inside the ui:selectInput

```
selectProd : function(component, event, helper){
     console.log(component.find("cboProducto").get("v.oldValue")); //undefined
     console.info(component.find('cboProducto')); //this isn't helping me
     console.info(event); //idem as above
}
```

But I don't know how can I call the old value

#### Getting it from a change event handler

*Component*

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.cboProducto}" action="{!c.changeProd}"/>
```

*Controller*

```
changeProd : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log(event.getParam('value'));
    console.log(event.getParam('oldValue'));
}
```

But none of the console.log are showing up

Comment: Why you need the old value?

Comment: I want to disable and enable the options because the select is inside an iteration and the user isn't allowed to repeat the options selected, and to enable one option I want to know which was previously selected so I can change the status to re-enable it.

Comment: I think for this you can take help of **Attribute**  `<aura:attribute name="oldValue" type="String" />`

Comment: Or you could just evaluate which options should be enabled or disabled based not he current selections. No need for the old value then.

Comment: -facepalm- so true, how I doidn't think on that?... submit your answers so I can vote them